# Webstorm IDE missing Node.js Boilerplate Project type

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, webstorm

So I just retrieved web storm specifically for learning and developing with node.js. It seems that all the documentation for Webstorm points to an existing project type consisting of a boilerplate node.js setup without all of the web configurations and such. I would like to use this boilerplate template rather the express template that has a bunch of web crap and unnecessary files. When loading up the application and selecting a project type, only the express template is listed.

Their documentation and examples list the template as such: [info](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/01/getting-started-with-node-js-in-webstorm/)

They also list it here: [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/create-new-project.html)

With a repo link to the template here: [template](https://github.com/robrighter/node-boilerplate)

I would like to know how I can enable this project type in web storm?

(Currently running web storm 8 v8.0.2)

Comment: this template has been removed; we don't plan to support it anymore due to some problems installing in on Windows. The template is quite old, hasn't been updated for a long time. IOf you like to create a project using it, follow the instructions at https://github.com/robrighter/node-boilerplate to create the needed files and then open the generated project directory as a project in WebStorm (File/Open)

Comment: @ironic, please vote for [WEB-14401](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14401)