# NodeJS project types missing in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I just installed the full version of WebStorm 9 for Node development, but when I go to make a new project, none of the suggestions are node-related:
[image]

I expected there to be at least a basic node template, and hopefully an Express template as mentioned in [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/generating-a-project-from-a-framework.html). I realise that the NodeJS Boilerplate template seems to [have been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544463/webstorm-ide-missing-node-js-boilerplate-project-type), but there should still be Express templates, no?

Node and NPM are installed, and they seem to be configured properly:
[image]

Comment: I was just wondering the same thing!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you should use scrollbar :)

*Update Note:* The problem is resolved for WS10 because the new project wizard. [WS10 EAP info.](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/02/webstorm-10-eap/)

Comment: Let us never speak of this again

Comment: Thats probably most hilarious PROPER answer i've ever seen on SO  :). Sorry that happened Miguel, but You two made my day :).

Comment: Ha. Me too. I saw anstarovoyt's answer and though 'let us never speak of this again'. Then read Miguel's comment. So funny.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't vote, because I just created an account (how I didn't have one in 18 years of development work is beyond me) to comment on Andrew's post. I'm saddened to realize that I did this EXACT same thing and I actually found the answer here. Incredibly, incredibly humiliated. Miquel's response was golden and sums up my exact feelings.

To sum up:

Answer: Scroll bar in the drop-down list. Missed it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have "Node.js Express App" in WebStorm 9 EAP 139.164

[image]