# I can't create a new node.js project with webstorm 9.0.1

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I just installed the webstorm 9.0.1 trial windows version, and when I try to create a new project in the project type list I don't see any reference to node.js applications.
  I see in all the documentation that node.js project template is supported.
  I'm missing something?

thanks,
  Luca

Comment: when you created the new project, did you select "node.js Express App" from Project Type combo box?

Comment: I don't see this project type in the list, this is the problem

Comment: Hmm... that's odd. I used the mac version but just install WS on my windows machine and tried to create a new project.  It also popped up a dialog box with 3 fields:  Project Name, Location, and Project Type (combo box with Nodejs Express App option).  Is there a scrollbar for that list?  Maybe it's hidden.  You might need to scroll down

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit late, but perhaps the boilerplate samples were removed from 9.01?  I'm showing the same thing and came across this post regarding version 8 -

[Webstorm IDE missing Node.js Boilerplate Project type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544463/webstorm-ide-missing-node-js-boilerplate-project-type)

EDIT :

And omg, the issue was I didn't scroll down :)  I don't see the boilerplate app referenced in the above link, but there is an Express seed app.

[NodeJS project types missing in WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606447/nodejs-project-types-missing-in-webstorm)

[image]

Comment: LMAO, I missed the scrolling part too

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see any reference to Node.js, then you're most likely missing the plugin.

Go to `File` > `Settings` > `Plugins` and check if `NodeJS` is visible and checked. If it's not there, select `Browse repositories`, select `NodeJS` and `Install plugin` and restart your IDE.